# how to play audio using audiotrack in android

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app that will play mp3 files. However the mp3 files are encrypted on the sd card . Either ways, after decryption, i'll have a stream of bytes. I hav used audio track class but unable to play the audio.plz help me.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the stream to a temporary (mp3) file and then play this file with `MediaPlayer`

***EDIT*** to address comment:
The file would not be persistent, something like

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("whatever", "mp3", getCacheDir());
temp.deleteOnExit();
FileOutputStream fStream = new FileOutputStream(temp);
fStream.write(passYourStream);
fStream.close(); 
FileInputStream fStream2 = new FileInputStream(temp);
yourMediaPlayerInstance.setDataSource(fStream2.getFD());
```

Comment: thanks for responding, but i want to use audio track and i dont want to save the stream to files. i ant to play directly the stream of bytes.

Comment: the file would just be used as a cache - nothing persistent. I've edited my answer to clarify

Comment: but in my project i should not use any temp files also.

Comment: how should i play using audiotrack class?

Comment: MediaPlayer is your friend [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Has anyone found a way to bypass the need for file-creation? I would also like to know how to use InputStream directly...

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think it is useful to you http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android24MediaB.html#AudioPlay